# Application crashes after loading dozens of textures

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, png

I noticed that when I load up a few dozen textures, my app crashes without any notice or so. It just returns to the phone's previous screen. Could it be because the phone cannot store that much in the memory? Should I not load all the textures before the game starts?

Comment: Please report the size of the textures, the number of them and an excerpt of your code to better help you :)

This way it is like, my car didn't start, what is the problem? :) :)

Comment: total size of textures is 3.2mb, with an average of 100kb per image. There are a total of 27 PNGs, each 1024 x 1024 in resolution.

Comment: mmmm quite a lot of content man. If you consider that a 1024 * 1024 texture in RGBA is 4 MB each, multiplied by 27 is about 110 MB of video RAM. I dont' believe all the devices around support that amount of video memory + all the geometries.

Comment: oh. don't actually know that much. thanks a lot @MaurizioBenedetti! So, should I unload unused textures and not load yet to be used textures?

Comment: @Mysterious Letter Unfortunately video RAM is a game design constraint and must be taken into consideration accordingly. Consider that if you are in android environment, there are so many GPUs and video RAM available that it is very hard to define a limit.

Comment: Ahuh. Thanks a lot! Will take note of that. Thanks for the advice @MaurizioBenedetti!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got your answer already as part of the comments, but I'll write this conclusion here:

The size of your assets in storage doesn't matter, as they are probably compressed. What matters is the size of the actual working set. In the case of images you can calculate it as

```
width * height * sizeof(pixel)
```

where

```
sizeof(pixel) = sum[channels]{ sizeof(channel) }
```

In the case of 1024x1024, 4 channels (RGBA), 1 byte per channel your working set size of a single texture would be:

```
1024*1024 = 1Mi
1Mi * 4 * 1B = 4MiB
```

In the case of 27 texture this amounts to `27*4MiB = 108MiB`. Now OpenGL defined in terms on an abstract machine, which means you cannot ask it, how many memory there is for you to spend. It will just tell you if it runs out of memory. OpenGL may also use normal system RAM if not everything fits into video RAM. Either way, on a handheld device you'll likely run out of memory if trying to upload over 100MiB of texture data.

> Should I not load all the textures before the game starts?

No, you should not. It is in fact better to "stream" your game's contents, load things on demand. Also some kind of garbage collection or recycling scheme helps a lot. Allocating a texture is expensive (i.e. a call to glTexImage), whereas replacing the data is cheap (glTexSubImage), so what I suggest is adding a "unused" counter to your texture management structure. Everytime you bind the texture and draw from it, you set it to zero. After finishing a frame increment the "unused" counter of each texture object. If you need to load a new texture you iterate over all texture objects, select those with a matching format (same size and number of channels), sorted by the unused counter, then reuse the texture object with the median of the "unused" values, i.e. in the middle of the sorted set of "unused". Every "higher unused" texture should be freed, the others stay as reserve. If you need to allocate more than one texture (likely) first allocate from the N median objects. Using that strategy keeps you an supply of ready to use texture object and also occasionally frees up unused memory.

Answer (score 1):

To recap the comments, by allocating so may textures, 27 in total of a 1024 by 1024 pixels in an RGBA mode, you allocate 4 MB of video ram each time per texture, for a total of 110 MB.

In order to avoid this kind of crashes and to be compatible with multiple Android systems, you should downsize the size of the textures (sometimes decreasing the overall quality).

Is is useless to say that the textures must be unloaded once they are not used anymore in order to make room for other new loads.